# c# Oracle Dynamic Connection string solution

Tags: c#, oracle, devexpress, database-connection, connection-string

I have an application that connects to specific Oracle user & database with data provided by user through one little form.

User inputs Username, Password and host address and can connect to any user defined locally, in the oracle client's file: tnsnames.ora. That works fine, but I have a problem when designing a reports with `devexpress` (or any other reports designer tool) for that same application.

All devexpress reports are communicating with database tables through dataset which uses fixed, hardcoded values defined in the connection string in app.config.

The problem is that I can't have hardcoded values for connecting to database, because user can every time enter different values and connect to a different user on database, through that little connection form, when the application is already running.
So does anyone know the best way to deal with this?

I don't know, maybe replacing the connection string in app.config every time when user inputs connection data?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static connection string that is for your reports and a separate one for your Oracle db/user connection.

Comment: Thanks Brent for your answer,

Comment: But my reports should also be dynamic, often connecting to a different db user... :/
Unfortunately i found the official devexpress answer which i believe says that it is not realy recommendable..
[link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q474553)